# Controlling where sphinx generated .rst files are saved

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

Suppose the following documentation structure for sphinx:

```
doc
 |_ _static
 |_ _templates
 |_ api
     |_ index.rst
     |_ classes.rst
     |_ functions.rst
 |_ index.rst
 |_ more_functions.rst
 |_ conf.py
```

And that `classes.rst`, `functions.rst` and `more_functions.rst` have classes and functions to auto-document with `autodoc/autosummary`. The build will generate `.rst` files for those classes and functions in:

- `doc/generated` for `more_functions.rst`
- `doc/api/generated` for `classes.rst` and `functions.rst`

Is there a way to control where those `generated` folders are created?

---

I'm trying to get a unique `generated` folder in the end. In this case, with this structure:

```
doc
 |_ generated
     |_ generated-from-more-functions.rst
     |_ api
         |_ generated-from-api/classes.rst
         |_ generated-from-api/functions-rst
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is such native functionality in `sphinx`.

The fastest way to achieve this without many headaches is to create a shell script to run the build and then move (with `mv` or `rm` if you're on gnu/linux) the files according to your needs.

Answer (score -2):

According to [Sphinx documentation](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-build.html), you can run `sphinx-build` with the option `BUILDDIR`.

> BUILDDIR
> The build directory to use instead of the one chosen in sphinx-quickstart.

I guess the default folders that you have mentioned are technically chosen by `sphinx-quickstart`.

example:

```bash
sphinx-build -b html sourcedir builddir
```

You can run the command through a [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) or using [os.system(command)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system).

Comment: The build directory is where e.g. the `html` pages will end up. By default `_build`. This has nothing to do with the location where `autodoc` saves the generated `.rst` files.